# IOS high resolution UIImage takes up little memory

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a `UIImage`. Its resolution  is  `2560 × 17722`.
When  I  load  the  UIImage, I find that the memory increase from  **12M  to 14M**  in Xcode.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView new];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"];
```

I  think  the  UIImage  takes up memory  should be  `2560 *17722*3` bytes 
Why  the  UIImage  takes  up  so little  memory;
the  image  url is    http://cdn.u2.huluxia.com/g2/M02/AD/CF/wKgBa1iA67SAUdSQAA1_myDzLw83123.ht

Comment: I'm having the same bug with another image, would be great if someone help answer this